# Java Web Start - Access environment variable java.io.tmpdir in jnlp

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, environment-variables, jnlp, java-web-start

I try to configure the path of the osgi instance and configuration folders in order to start my Eclipse RCP application. To do that I configure the following within the  tag in the jnlp file:

```xml
<!-- Information usually specified in the config.ini -->
<property name="osgi.instance.area" value="@java.io.tmpdir"/>
<property name="osgi.configuration.area" value="@java.io.tmpdir"/>
```

Unfortunately "java.io.tmpdir" is interpreted as a literal and not as an environment variable. Configuring the path to user.home works fine, but thats not what I want as my user home is located on a network device and my %TEMP% is located on my local drive c:

In any examples I found the configuration is as the following using user.home:

```xml
<!-- Information usually specified in the config.ini -->
<property name="osgi.instance.area" value="@user.home/Application Data/demo"/>
<property name="osgi.configuration.area" 
   value="@user.home/Application Data/demo"/>
```

I tried it with JDK 1.6.0_27 and 1.6.0_37 on Windows Vista.

I will be thankful for any help as I´m stuck on this issue for a while now.

Comment: *"Unfortunately "java.io.tmpdir" is interpreted as a literal and not as an environment variable."*  I think it is quite fortunate.  If you could draw that data into the JNLP at run-time, it would be a security bug.

Comment: At least it´s possible with the "user.home" environment variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little late, but I still want to post my solution:

I worte a custom Launcher class and configured it in my JNLP file (< application-desc main-class="de.my.package.launcher.Launcher">). 
In my Launcher class, I set the desired variables and afterwards I call the main method of the Equinox Launcher.
I know that´s not a very charming solution, but at least it works ;-)

Answer (score 0):

[The Eclipse runtime options](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html) document which arguments are available and which locations you can address (e.g. osgi.user.area, osgi.install.area...). Have a look at the Locations section. Beware that those locations resolve differently when starting an Eclipse RCP locally or via WebStart.

Comment: Thanks for the link. As I have to solve the problem anyway, I decided to Write my own Launcher class and set the Property there.